# Merging Two Databases - How to Skip Same ID or Generate New ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL databases. I would like to data from one database to another. Both have the same structure and entries except that one database has same IDs for different items within the same tables. I don't want to replace the data from the old to the new database. If IDs are there, I would like the new database to skip it. If it's a duplication, I would like a new ID to be generated.

I'd like to use phpmyadmin for this but have no idea if this is even possible.

Comment: So are you asking for code to be written or a tool to be linked? Either way, this seems off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

> 0.) Make backup of both tables

PHPMYADMIN will be sufficient for your request.
First you need to ensure there is no duplicating id's or primary keys.
Assuming two tables `testtable1` and `testtable2` have columns `testtable_id, name`

1.) firstly you would make query on second table

```
UPDATE testtable2 SET testtable2.testtable_id = testtable2.testtable_id + (SELECT MAX( testtable1.testtable_id ) FROM testtable1);
```

2.) Than, again in `testtable2`, there is tool `Copy table to (database.table):` under `Operations menu`, set DB name and testtable1 name (db name should be already set), select Data only radio button option and click `Go`. 3.) Now, you have all data from both tables in `testtable1`.

---

Edit. Firstly I thought it is matter of two tables in same database. But nevertheless you can use step two for rest of the tables too. Just set correct DB and table name in step two. Also, before that, set query so expecting ID to be higher than MAX ID of table you want to extend. You can hard code parenthesis part with exact number of MAX ID first DB corresponding table.